# Graph Theory adjacency matrix

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

Is it possible for a graph to exist that meets these conditions?

For a Graph G, the adjacency matrix has all $1$’s in the first row and all $0$’s in the second row.

What I think: Such a graph cannot exist because if there were $1$’s in the first row, it means that v1 is connected to every single vertex in graph G. However, the second row being all $0$’s indicates that there is no vertex connected to v2, which is a contradiction?

Am I correct?

Also another question, with an adjacency matrix does a loop = 2 in the matrix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are dealing with an undirected graph, the adjcency matrix is a symmetric matrix. Hence, $a_{12} = a_{21}$. Hence, the adjacency matrix cannot represent an undirected graph.

However, if you are talking about adjacency matrix for a directed graph, then the second row can be zero, if there are no edges emanating from the second vertex (depending on the convention you choose).

Comment: could you give me an example of such a directed graph or where to find one?

Comment: Wait, is this such a graph http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/matrix/images/directed-graphs/directed-graph.jpg -----WHERE A goes to everything and B goes to nothing? That would work wouldn't it?

Comment: example: row1: 11 row2: 00. loop of length 2 does exist in row1:111 row2:100 row3:000 (always assuming you deal with directed graphs)

Comment: Take any [star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_%28graph_theory%29) and convert it into a directed graph such that every edge becomes an outward-going arc. Then, also add a loop, an arc from the central node back to itself. If the central node's outward arcs is represented in the first row of the matrix, then you are done.

Answer (score 0):

> Also another question, with an adjacacny matrix does a loop = 2 in the matrix?

This is a matter of definition, and as such, we get to choose.  The obvious possibilities are $1$ or $2$.  So which is best?

In this case, there is a good reason for writing $1$ for a loop in the adjacency matrix.  Namely, provided we write $1$ for loops in the adjacency matrix,  if $A=(A[i,j])$ is the adjacency matrix of a graph, then $A^k[i,j]$ is the number of walks from $i$ to $j$ of length $k$.

However, for the vertex's degree, it can be better to count a loop as contributing $2$, otherwise the [Handshaking Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) doesn't work (or, at least, would need adjusting).